# Unable to call function while using requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have been working on a new project for sometime and recently started using `require.js` in the project.

It all seemed to work fine until I tried making a call from `application.js` to `dashboard.js` when the tab `#dailyTab` or `#weeklyTab` was clicked or access varialbe `var a` in dashboard,js. My code is below

**main.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl : '../static/js/',
    paths : {
        'jquery' : 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min',
        'jquery-ui' : 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min',
        'bootstrap' : ['//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/js/bootstrap.min', 'bootstrap.min'],
    },
    shim : {
        'bootstrap' : ['jquery'],
        'bootswatch' : ['bootstrap'],
    }
});

require(["jquery", "jquery-ui", "bootstrap", "dashboard", "application"], function($, jui, bootstrap, dashboard, application) {
    $("#myTab a:first").tab("show");
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err)
});
```

**dashboard.js**

```
define(function() {
    var a = 10;
    var Reload = {
        dailyCharts : function() {
            console.log("Daily Charts");
        },
        weeklyCharts : function() {
            console.log("Weekly Charts");
        }
    };
    var Display = {
        none : function(node) {
            console.log("none");
        },
        block : function(node) {
            console.log("block");
        }
    }
});
```

**application.js**

```
define(["jquery", "dashboard"], function(jquery, dashboard) {
    $("#dailyTab").click(function() {
        dashboard.Reload.dailyCharts();
    });
    $("#weeklyTab").click(function() {
        dashboard.Reload.weeklyCharts();
    });
});
```

Can someone tell me what I have done wrong or what I can do to fix this issue. I accept my coding skills is not very good.

Any help on this is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your `dashboard.js` didn't return anything. How would `application.js` use it?

```
define(function() {
    var a = 10;
    var Reload : {...};
    var Display : {...};
    //return the interface
    return {
      Reload : Reload,
      Display : Display
    }
});
```

Comment: Earlier I tried wrapping them all together with a `return {}` , let me try putting the variables out of the block.

Comment: @shabeer90 you can return an object of references. You need not move all of the code into the returned object.